# Taskmanager dump - possible for analysis with java/eclipse memory analyzer?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, analyzer, heap-dump

Is it anyhow possible to use a process dump created by windows taskmanager for analysis on Eclipse Memory Analyzer?

At least Eclipse Memory Analyzer cannot open the dump. So is there any conversion? I already searched on google, but did not find anything, yet. So I think there is no way? Also here on Stackoverflow I did not find anything useable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

The dump must be from the Java virtual machine. The dump created by the Windows task manager is on machine code instead on bytecode level.

See in the [Memory Analyzer (MAT) help how to create a dump that can be analyzed with MAT](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/tasks/acquiringheapdump.html)